# Task bar not appearing in Ubuntu LXDE

Tags: lxde, taskbar

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, installed LXDE for the heck of it. Used it for a bit, then logged out and logged in. Now the taskbar isn't there, and there's a solid gray bar at the top of the screen (width roughly the same as that of the taskbar). What should I do?

Comment: Does anything happen after right clicking on the bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solid gray bar is your task bar. Right click it and click 'Panel Settings'.
You'll have to manually add everything you had on it.

**EDIT:** 
 The default LXDE panel file is stored at `/usr/share/lxpanel/profile/LXDE/panels`
Copy this to `~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE/panels` to restore the default configuration.

Comment: that sounds tedious, do you know a faster way? there must be some default setting stored somewhere, no?